# How to Calculate Torque to Prevent Rotating

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics

I'm stuck with how to calculate the external torque which must be applied to prevent the aircraft rotating about axis?

[image]

The imagine shows an aircraft which has a jet engine with a rotor that has an angular velocity of 6000 rpm and a moment of inertia of 10 kgm^2 (both about 0Z). If the aircraft moves into a dive by rotating about 0X at 3°/s, what external torque must be applied to the aircraft about 0Y in order to prevent it rotating about this axis?

I know that the torque required T = I⋅(Ω×ω) where I is the Moment of inertia, ω is the rotor angular velocity in rad/s and Ω is the precession rate but I'm confused about how to calculate these.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Angular momentum L is $ L= I\omega = 10kgm^2*2\pi*6000/60= 2\pi*6000kgm^2 $

$ \frac{d\phi}{dt}=3/s=0.016radian/s= \frac{1}{L} \tau $

$ \tau= 0.016*2\pi*6000=2\pi*100kgm^2 $

This torque must act at XZ plane 90 degrees to dive angle and in your coordinate shown is negative.

In a real situation, one needs to consider the angular momentum of the entire plane and the change in drag and lift.

Because the numbers are round I did the calculations in my head, check my work.

BTW. I am a private pilot and fly a single-engine, piston, Cessna 172. I have never had to consider this. Albeit we apply yaw correction by rudders for controlling the propeller's differential angle of attack.